# Manually update servceworker cache if cache name is different

Tags: javascript, service-worker

So I have a PWA and I want to add a button that lets user know that there is a new version availble so they can update all the files if they have internet connection. Everytime I run `gulp build` it adds a timestamp to service-worker cache name, so it is always fresh, but it doesn't update cached files.

Here is gulp task that does it:

```
gulp.task('serviceWorkerCache', function(){
    gulp.src(['dist/serviceworker.js'])
        .pipe(replace(/(dobrywebdev-\d{0,13})/g, function(match, p1, offset, string) {
            var currentDate = Date.now();
            return 'dobrywebdev-' + currentDate;
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And the whole service-worker.js file:

```
const CACHE_NAME = "dobrywebdev-1521013165219"; // that number is the timestamp that changes
const URLS_TO_CACHE  = [
    "/",
    "/index.html",
    "/errors/404.html",
    "/manifest.json",
    "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext",
    "/css/main.min.css",
    "/js/main.min.js",
    "/fonts/devicons.eot",
    "/fonts/devicons.svg",
    "/fonts/devicons.ttf",
    "/fonts/devicons.woff",
    "/font/fontello.eot",
    "/font/fontello.svg",
    "/font/fontello.ttf",
    "/font/fontello.woff",
    "/font/fontello.woff2",
    "/json/content-eng.json",
    "/json/content-pl.json",
    "/img/playground.png",
    "/img/agency.png",
    "/img/cv.png",
    "/img/dobrywebdev.png",
    "/img/dobrywebdevfb.png",
    "/img/form.png",
    "/img/interior.png",
    "/img/interior1.png",
    "/img/logo-dark.png",
    "/img/logo-light.png",
    "/img/simpleweather.png",
    "/img/sleszynski.png",
    "/img/todo.png",
    "/img/webdev37.png",
    "/android-chrome-36x36.png",
    "/android-chrome-48x48.png",
    "/android-chrome-72x72.png",
    "/android-chrome-96x96.png",
    "/android-chrome-144x144.png",
    "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
    "/android-chrome-256x256.png",
    "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
    "/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png",
    "/browserconfig.xml",
    "/favicon-16x16.png",
    "/favicon-32x32.png",
    "/mstile-150x150.png",
    "/safari-pinned-tab.svg"
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
        .then(function(cache) {
            console.log('Opened cache');
            return cache.addAll(URLS_TO_CACHE);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
    event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames
          .filter(name => name.includes("dobrywebdev") && name !== CACHE_NAME)
          .map(name => caches.delete(name))
      )
    }).then(() => self.clients.claim())
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }
            var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();
            return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
            function(response) {
                if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                    return response;
            }
            var responseToCache = response.clone();
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                .then(function(cache) {
                    cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                    });
                    return response;
                }
            );
        })
    );
});
```

And registeration in main.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js').then(function(registration) {
      console.log('Service worker registration done, scope is:', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
}
```

So basically I want to check if `CACHE_NAME` in serviceworker.js is different than the one in actual browser cache and show a button/pop-up with an option to update the app. That button then should delete the cache, unregister serviceworker, register a fresh one and add files to cache. From what I've read, serviceworker can't do anything DOM related, so I have to do it through main.js. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you need that to be honest as everytime you update the version of service worker the old one is deleted by the browser automatically. I think you need to include this piece of code somewhere in your service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
      .then(function (keyList) {
        return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});
```

This would delete the old cache and update service worker

Comment: Ok, your script seems to be working a little better than my previous one, because it clears whole cache, not just files in it - at least in Firefox. But in Chrome, even after closing the tab or force refreshing the page, cache doesn't update - I have to manually click on "Update" in "serviceworker" tab to update it or unregister it and then force refresh. Why is that and how can I change that?

Comment: try clearing the app data first in chrome and hard refresh the page then. if it works in firefox should be working in chrome.Then test again.

Comment: Tried it on different PC with previous cache version in Chrome and it seems to be working as it should, so that's great. But I'm still wondering, mostly out of curiosity - is there is a way to check the CONST value in serviceworker value and based on that show a modal/button with the option to update it manually, in case it doesn't work somehow?